# Why Mosfet FQP30N06L has weird behaviour?

Tags: mosfet

[image]

First, I know how MOSFET works.

I want to ask why on the left picture (Source with +5) always TURN ON the led, even Gate that I connected to pin already off?

The right one (Source with ground) is ok and works perfectly. When gate is off, led also turn off and vice versa.

What happen with (Souce with +5), is it should be same with the right one, right?

MOSFET TYPE: FQP30N06L

Comment: If you knew how mosfets work, you would know that there is such a thing as a body diode.

Comment: Not sure you do know how a MOSFET works... Look at the datasheet, it shows the body diode, showing you that the circuit you have on the left would just be a 5V rail conected to a diode, to a resistor to an LED to ground.

Comment: There are even some test circuits of the MOSFET in the datasheet

Comment: I thought I knew how MOSFET works. I should learn again. Thank you everyone. You guys rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the datasheet for your MOSFET](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FQ/FQP30N06L.pdf), you will see that the body diode is oriented to allow current to pass from source-to-drain (conventional current model) through the body diode, regardless of the state of the Gate.

In effect, you don't even have a transistor in your first circuit; just a voltage source, resistor & 2 forward-biased diodes (one being the LED).

- NOTE: In the future, please try to use the *circuit editor* from the question editing tools to make schematics (unless you're on a touch-screen device), as it makes schematics which are more easily read (and includes access to circuit simulation).